Error importing DataWeave file in MUnit tests: Invalid input with double colon
Error importing DataWeave file in MUnit tests: Invalid input with double colon
Question
I'm trying to use a DataWeave file named testing_intro_response located in the testing-intro folder inside the Assert Expression connector while unit testing a flow. This folder is created under the src/test/resources section.
Here's the code inside the testing_intro_response.dwl file:
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::test::Asserts 
---
payload must equalTo(
    {
        "fullName": "Kendrick Lamar"
    }
)

MUnit Configuration XML
Here is the relevant configuration of my MUnit suite:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:munit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/munit"
      xmlns:munit-tools="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/munit-tools"
      xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
          http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/munit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/munit/current/mule-munit.xsd
          http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/munit-tools  http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/munit-tools/current/mule-munit-tools.xsd">
    <munit:config name="munit-testing-intro-test-suite.xml" />
    <munit:test name="mule-intro-api-success-test-case-assert-expression" doc:id="some-id">
        <munit:execution>
            <munit:set-event doc:name="Set Event">
                <munit:attributes value='#[{queryParams: {"firstName": "Kendrick", "lastName": "Lamar"}}]' />
            </munit:set-event>
            <flow-ref name="munit-testing-introFlow" />
        </munit:execution>
        <munit:validation>
            <munit-tools:assert doc:name="Assert expression">
                <munit-tools:that><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
import testing-intro::testing_intro_response
---
testing_intro_response::main({payload: payload})]]]></munit-tools:that>
            </munit-tools:assert>
        </munit:validation>
    </munit:test>
</mule>

Error Message
When running the test suite, I receive the following error:
Invalid input "-i", expected Alpha Numeric Character, ,, '!' or ~ (line 2, column 15):

If I use the DataWeave expression directly in the Assert Expression connector, the test runs successfully. Is there an issue with how I'm importing testing_intro_response.dwl? I've tried different syntaxes without success.
Additional Information

MuleSoft Version: 4.7.0
MUnit Version: 3.2.1

MUnit Version:
Any help would be appreciated!
